# IMAP PHP subject convert in some weird format

Tags: php, base64, imap

I am using imap for download mail in my local system, but some time subject of some mails converted in strange text

Oringinal subject text:

> 2 TO 10 JAN @ 9999 PER ROOM - 5* RESORT NORTH GOA !!!

Converted subject text:

> [Newsletters] =?utf-8?Q?2=20TO=2010=20JAN=20@=209999=20PER=20ROOM=20-=205*=20RESORT=20NORTH=20GOA=20!!!?=

So is there any solution for get proper text?

Comment: yes, use [imap_mime_header_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mime-header-decode.php) function.